# NSWindow: get the current Space/Desktop of a specific window

Tags: macos, cocoa

Is there a way to get the current Space/Desktop of a specific NSWindow?

for example:
**myWindow.spaceIndex**

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem was: 
Are two different windows both on the active space?

The NSWindow has a property **.isOnActiveSpace**, so:

```
let areOnActiveSpace = firstWindow.isOnActiveSpace && secondWindow.isOnActiveSpace
```

Comment: I think that it shouldn't work as expected if you have more than 2 spaces. They could be in different non-active space, no?

Comment: You are right. In my case this solution works pretty well because there is always a window in the active space, but as you suggest, this doesn't track if the windows are in the same space, but if they are both on the active space. ( I edited the post )